# ajax hide load more button on no more data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, yii

I have implemented the load more functionality using `ajax` in `yii`. This is what I am doing in my `script`:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).on('click', '.discover-more', function() {
            $('.discover-more').hide();
            $('.loading').show();
            var lastId = $('ul#ulscroller li:last').attr('id');
            $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                type: 'POST',
                url: '<?php echo $host . $url . '/index.php?r=site/LoadMore&lastid=' ?>' + lastId,
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#ulscroller').append(data);
                    $('.discover-more').show();
                    $('.loading').hide();
                    if (data.length() == 0) {
                        $('.discover-more').hide();
                        $('.nomore').show();
                    } 


                }


            });
        });
    });
```

Now, what i have to do is to hide discover more button when there are no more `images` to show. I have tried a couple of methods in the `success` call back, like `if(data.length() == 0)` and `if(data.size() < 1)` but both do not seem to work? any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
if($.trim(data).length == 0)
```

hope this will work !

Comment: glad to help !! Happy coding :D

Comment: would you care to explain why `trim` made a difference?

Comment: `data` variable might be containing some white spaces or tabs or newline character. So if we check its length it will include these spaces and return its length.try `var testVar = "   ";
 console.log(testVar.length);` I have given 3 blank spaces so length will be returned as 3. '$.trim()' will strip all these blank spaces and return its length.

Comment: oh... Well explained, thanks. You may add it to the original answer for any one else who comes looking for this.. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

`.length` without `()`, it is a `property` and not a `method`.

```
if (data == "") {
                        $('.discover-more').hide();
                        $('.nomore').show();
                      }
```